# Invalid postback or callback argument (HiddenField and container Visible=false)

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, postback, asynchronous-postback

I've not found answers that matched my circumstances, so I'm posting an answered question hoping it will help others.

I was getting the error

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

```
   at System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId, String argument)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.ValidateEvent(String uniqueID, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

I've got a Databound ListView (with a few 100s rows), with buttons on each row. The buttons bring a popup. The popup has dropdownlists and other controls doing asynchronous postbacks. I need to make sure I do asynchronous postbacks to avoid refreshing my big table.

I get the error when I click the button on one row, then change a dropdownlist inside the popup which fires a postback (selected item changed). Boom.

Here's the markup for a reduced sample, without popup and javascript at all! It still exhibits the problem. Click twice on a button in a row to get the error.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestPopupAsynchPostback.Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptMgr" runat="server" ScriptMode="Debug" EnablePartialRendering="true"
            EnableScriptGlobalization="true" EnableScriptLocalization="true" EnablePageMethods="true"/>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ListDataSource" runat="server" SelectMethod="List" TypeName="TestPopupAsynchPostback.Default" />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="PageLabel"></asp:Label>
        <asp:ListView ID="EL" runat="server" DataSourceID="ListDataSource" OnItemDataBound="EntityList_OnItemDataBound">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" enableviewstate="false">
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr runat="server" id="DefaultRow" enableviewstate="false">
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Lbl" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button runat="server" type="button" id="ReportingButton" enableviewstate="false" onserverclick="ReportingButton_OnClick" causesvalidation="false">click</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <%-- Fix part 1: Change SpecialRow  visible = true--%>
                <tr runat="server" id="SpecialRow" visible="false" enableviewstate="false">
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Lbl2" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" />
                        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="fn_hid" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace TestPopupAsynchPostback
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);
            PageLabel.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString() + " IsPostBack:" + IsPostBack + " IsInAsyncPostBack:" + (sm == null ? "" : sm.IsInAsyncPostBack.ToString());
        }

        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
            if (sm != null)
            {
                foreach (ListViewDataItem row in EL.Items)
                {
                    HtmlButton reportingButton = row.FindControl("ReportingButton") as HtmlButton;
                    if (reportingButton != null)
                        sm.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(reportingButton);
                }
            }
            base.Render(writer);
        }

        public IList<string> List()
        {
            return (new string[] { "ONE", "TWO"}).ToList();
        }

        protected void ReportingButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Do something useful here, for now, just a postback event
        }

        protected void EntityList_OnItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
        {
            Label lbl = e.Item.FindControl("Lbl") as Label;
            Label lbl2 = e.Item.FindControl("Lbl2") as Label;
            lbl.Text = lbl2.Text = e.Item.DataItem.ToString();

            HtmlTableRow specialRow = e.Item.FindControl("SpecialRow") as HtmlTableRow;
            if (e.Item.DataItemIndex%2 == 0)
            {
                HiddenField fn_hid = e.Item.FindControl("fn_hid") as HiddenField;
                fn_hid.Value = "test1";
                specialRow.Visible = true;
            }
            //Fix part 2: set SpecialRow Visible = false in code behind
            //else
            //    specialRow.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I initially thought my javascript was at fault as I am modifying things with it. However, the process of creating a sample page has helped me find the problem.

It turns out it has nothing to do with the javascript or the popup. It's to do with a HiddenField contained inside a TR HtmlControl (asp.net server side control) with Visible=false IN THE MARKUP. I then use the code behind to set Visible=true when I need to in OnItemDataBound event.

**This is what is causing the error for me:** It seems that because the container (the TR SpecialRow) is Visible=false, I guess something is not rendered. I then come along in OnItemDataBound, decide that this row must be shown, and set Visible=true and set the value of my HiddenField. Boom.
If I remove the markup for the hidden field and don't set its value, no crash.
So it's not just the visibility of the TR on its own, it's the HiddenField too.

**My fix:** don't set Visible=false in the markup, and change OnItemDataBound to set Visible=false when required.

**In other words:** I was defaulting to hide things in markup and use code behind to show them. I changed this around and show things by default in markup and hide them using the code behind.

*I've added the fix in the markup and code above.*